# Is it possible to use a list of fields to query a model in Django

Tags: django, arraylist, django-queryset

At the outset, let me be upfront that I am not too comfortable with what I am trying to achieve.

But, here it is:

I am trying to query a random **model** in my app for which the field names would be passed at runtime.

Something like:

```
fields_list = [field1, field2, ...]
qs_target_model = target_model.values(fields_list) #, field3)
```

Using the above setup, I get an error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

**The reason** I am trying to do this: Both the model and its fields would be selected at **runtime**!!

**My question is:**

Is what I am trying to do possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, fields_list must be the fields of model

```
fields_list = [field1, field2, ...]
qs_target_model = target_model.values(*fields_list) #, field3)
```